# Sonata Admin Unable to load the "Sonata\CoreBundle\Twig\Extension\FlashMessageRuntime" runtime

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using `sonata-project/admin-bundle: ^3.0` and `sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle: ^3.0  with symfony 2.8.*` . while browsing `localhost/admin/dashboard` i got following error,

> Unable to load the
>   "Sonata\CoreBundle\Twig\Extension\FlashMessageRuntime" runtime.

What might be the cause of the error?

Comment: Same issue here, did a composer update.

Comment: The same process( as provided in official sonata documentation) to install sonata, works in symfony 3.4. It works previously in symfony 2.8 as well. Maybe the result of composer update. I tried to work in fresh project of symfony 2.8 as well but it shows the same error.

Comment: What happened with this issue? I have the same issue w/ the version "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.42". I had to override the core standard_layout.html.twig and comment this line {% include '@SonataCore/FlashMessage/render.html.twig' %}

Comment: @system7 update "sonata-project/core-bundle" there was error in last commits (see fix: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/commit/266c2655cfb86c78e79b30243e50b2519c546476)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround is to set the core-bundle version in composer to

```
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "3.10.0",
```

Same error if we try to go above this version.

UPDATE : we found that you can get this error if you are running Symfony 2.8. This runtime works only with versions > 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. Looks like with `sonata-project/admin-bundle` version 3.36.0 is the problem solved.